# Device not receiving payload messages, but receiving registration messages

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Currently building an android app using c2dm, pushing messages from a site built on app engine. I have followed numerous tutorials and so far...

- I have made an account with c2dm and have gotten it approved
- Have my device registering with the C2DM servers (receiveing the registration Id)
- Pushing this registration Id along with the device's linked email to my app which is storing it.
- Sending off request to Google's ClientLogin, and getting back a valid Auth token.
- Firing off the post request to the C2DM servers with the payload, regId, and auth token. I'm receiving back an "Ok" status code (200) from the c2dm servers as well. So I'm assuming it went through alright.

But, my device just sits there, not getting any messages what so ever. I have spent the last week tearing the project apart and rebuilding it from scratch many times, and it always comes back to the device simply not receiving the payload message. I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

**Could there be a problem with my account? Is there anyway for me to check on pending messages on the C2DM server?**

Bits of code:
Android Manifest

```
<permission android:name="skaught.wingman.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="skaught.wingman.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="C2DReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <!-- Receive registration ids -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="skaught.wingman" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Receive actual messages -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="skaught.wingman" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    ....
```

Sending push to C2DM Servers

```
payload = {
    "data.payload" : "Please Work!",
    "registration_id": regId,
    "collapse_key": hash(email),
}
encodedPayload = urllib.urlencode(payload)
url = "http://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/send"

#Make a POST request to C2DM server
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
                        payload=encodedPayload,
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        headers={   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    'Authorization': 'GoogleLogin auth=' + authToken}
                        )
```

Receiving C2DM Messages on Android

```
public class C2DReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
    public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Received a Message");        
        if (Constants.RECEIVED_REGISTRATION_ID_FROM_GOOGLE.equals(intent.getAction())) {            
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Received a registration ID from Google.");
            handleRegistration(context, intent);
        } else if (Constants.RECEIVED_C2DM_MESSAGE_FROM_GOOGLE.equals(intent.getAction())) {            
            //I'm NEVER reached!
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Received a C2DM message from Google.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the email-id that you use to get the registration-id on the phone and the email-id you use to fetch the auth-token are the **same**.

Also make sure that your payload doesn't cross 1024 chars. There is a 1024 char limit for the payload.

You also have to make sure the package name you registered with the email-id at the time of approval is the same. I am assuming you have done this.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you must receive registration-id from C2DM to your device
2. Use this device register-id in your app server and get authentication token
3. Use this authentication and device registration-id to send payload

But as you are not following this in sequence, so your device registration-id is getting changed again, but you are using the old id. So you are unable to get message in your device
as you are executing like this.

Follow the sample application provided here in CHAPTER 4:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html